# Tic Tac Toe Science Fair AI and Strategy

Tags: javascript, artificial-intelligence, computer-science, tic-tac-toe

I am doing a science fair project about doing a javascript Artificial Intelligence Game with different strategies, and seeing which one beats the most humans.
I am not sure how to put in the AI or the strategy, please help.

A two player example of my game: [http://xenoffpi.no-ip.org/preston/tictactoe](http://xenoffpi.no-ip.org/preston/tictactoe/)

Here is my code:

```
<HTML> 
<HEAD> 

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Shadows+Into+Light' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Crafty+Girls' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<TITLE>Tic Tac Toe!</TITLE> 

<SCRIPT TYPE="TEXT/JAVASCRIPT"> 
var xTurn = true; 
var gameOver = false; 
var numMoves = 0; 

function squareclicked(square) 

{ 
var value = square.value; 
var status = document.getElementById('status'); 

if(gameOver) 
{ 
alert("The game is already over."); 
return; 
} 

if(value != 'X' && value != 'O') 
{ 
if(xTurn) 
{ 
numMoves++; 
square.value = 'X'; 
xTurn = false; 
status.innerHTML = 'O\'s turn'; 
} 
else 
{ 
numMoves++; 
square.value = 'O'; 
xTurn = true; 
status.innerHTML = 'X\'s turn'; 
} 
} 
else 
alert('That square has already been played.'); 

var winner = checkWin(); 
if(!winner) 
{ 

if(numMoves == 9) 
status.innerHTML = 'Tie Game!'; 
} 
else 
gameOver = true; 

} 

function newgame() 
{ 
var status = document.getElementById('status'); 

xTurn = true; 
status.innerHTML = 'X\'s turn'; 
gameOver = false; 
numMoves = 0; 

for(var x = 0; x < 3; x++) 
{ 
for(var y = 0; y < 3; y++) 
{ 
document.getElementById(x + '_' + y).value = ' '; 
} 
} 
} 

function checkWin() 
{ 
var status = document.getElementById('status'); 
var val0; 
var val1; 
var val2; 


for(var y = 0; y < 3; y++) 
{ 
val0 = document.getElementById('0_'+y).value; 
val1 = document.getElementById('1_'+y).value; 
val2 = document.getElementById('2_'+y).value; 
if(val0 == 'X' && val1 == 'X' && val2 == 'X') 
{ 
status.innerHTML = "X WINS!"; 
return true; 
} 
else if(val0 == 'O' && val1 == 'O' && val2 == 'O') 
{ 
status.innerHTML = "O WINS!"; 
return true; 
} 
} 


for(var x = 0; x < 3; x++) 
{ 
val0 = document.getElementById(x + '_0').value; 
val1 = document.getElementById(x + '_1').value; 
val2 = document.getElementById(x + '_2').value; 
if(val0 == 'X' && val1 == 'X' && val2 == 'X') 
{ 
status.innerHTML = "X WINS!"; 
return true; 
} 
else if(val0 == 'O' && val1 == 'O' && val2 == 'O') 
{ 
status.innerHTML = "O WINS!"; 
return true; 
} 
} 


val0 = document.getElementById('0_0').value; 
val1 = document.getElementById('1_1').value; 
val2 = document.getElementById('2_2').value; 
if(val0 == 'X' && val1 == 'X' && val2 == 'X') 
{ 
status.innerHTML = "X WINS!"; 
return true; 
} 
else if(val0 == 'O' && val1 == 'O' && val2 == 'O') 
{ 
status.innerHTML = "O WINS!"; 
return true; 
} 


val0 = document.getElementById('2_0').value; 
val1 = document.getElementById('1_1').value; 
val2 = document.getElementById('0_2').value; 
if(val0 == 'X' && val1 == 'X' && val2 == 'X') 
{ 
status.innerHTML = "X WINS!"; 
return true; 
} 
else if(val0 == 'O' && val1 == 'O' && val2 == 'O') 
{ 
status.innerHTML = "O WINS!"; 
return true; 
} 


} 

</SCRIPT> 

<style>


input[type=button] {
    color:#08233e;
background-color: #9999FF;
    font-family: 'Crafty Girls', cursive;
    font-size:70%;
   width: 100;
height:100;
    cursor:pointer;
font-size:25;
border:groove;
border-color: 000000;
font-weight:900;
}

input[type=button]:hover {
    background-color:#6666FF;
}


input[id="NEWGAME"] {
    color:#08233e;
background-color: #9999FF;
   width: 310;
height:60;
    cursor:pointer;
font-size:30;
font-family: 'Shadows Into Light', cursive;

}

input[id=NEWGAME]:hover {
    background-color:#6666FF;


}

#status{
font-family: 'Shadows Into Light', cursive;
font-size:30;
font-style:bold;
font-weight:900;
}

#stat{
background-color:#9999FF;
width:302;
height:50
}

#outline{
width:400;
height:530;
background-color:000000;

}


#header{
height:100;
width:800;
background-color:000000;
}
</style>
</HEAD> 

<BODY>

<div align="center">
<div id="outline">
<br>
<br>
<INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" ID="NEWGAME" VALUE="New Game" ONCLICK="newgame();">
<br>
<br>
<INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" ID="0_0" VALUE=" " ONCLICK="squareclicked(this);"> 
<INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" ID="1_0" VALUE=" " ONCLICK="squareclicked(this);"> 
<INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" ID="2_0" VALUE=" " ONCLICK="squareclicked(this);"> 
<BR> 
<INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" ID="0_1" VALUE=" " ONCLICK="squareclicked(this);"> 
<INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" ID="1_1" VALUE=" " ONCLICK="squareclicked(this);"> 
<INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" ID="2_1" VALUE=" " ONCLICK="squareclicked(this);"> 
<BR> 
<INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" ID="0_2" VALUE=" " ONCLICK="squareclicked(this);"> 
<INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" ID="1_2" VALUE=" " ONCLICK="squareclicked(this);"> 
<INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" ID="2_2" VALUE=" " ONCLICK="squareclicked(this);"> 
<br>

<div align="center">
<div id="stat"> 
<P ID="status">X's turn</P>
</div>
</div>
</div> 
 </div>


</BODY> 
</HTML>
```

Comment: I found this xkcd comic relevant: http://xkcd.com/832/

Answer (score 0):

Since you can calculate the entire decision tree for tic tac toe easily and quickly, the Minimax algorithm will make it so that your ai will never lose:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax

It won't always win (most humans will play it to a cat's game), but it is guaranteed not to lose.